# Code-first migration errors with EntityFramework Identity foreign keying

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I have a model class defined like so:

```
public class Request
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Requester")]
    public string RequesterId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Requester { get; set; }
}
```

I'm simply making a foreign key relationship between a request and the user that made the request. However, when I try and perform an **Add-Migration**, I receive the following error:

> Project.DataContexts.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   Project.DataContexts.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.
>   IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.

I've looked around and the only similar situations are where people are using Fluent-API, with modelbinding. I'm however using data annotations. Any help on this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you exactly what the problem is. Your `IdentityUserLogin` and `IdentityUserRole` classes have no property that is marked with `[Key]` or can be interpreted as the primary key based on convention. Why you didn't both to post the classes that are explicitly mentioned in the exception is beyond me.

Comment: Because they are part of EntityFramework's Identity and weren't written by me, nor are they physically in my code they're in the EntityFramework library.

Comment: No, they aren't. It references Project.DataContexts as the namespace. That means there's a custom class there, that just happens to be named the same as the Identity classes. You are allowed to use your own entities with Identity, they just have to inherit from certain base classes or implement certain interfaces.

Comment: As the person who made this project, no, there are absolutely no custom classes in that namespace. In my data contexts folder, I have 2 folders for migrations, and 2 files which only contain class constructors for my Identity and Request contexts.

Comment: Don't know what to tell you, but arguing with me is not the solution. Either those classes exist, or there's an old build that includes them. Regardless, EF thinks they're there. The built-in Identity classes are all implemented properly or it wouldn't work for anyone. Clean your solution and rebuild, start a new solution, etc. Something is there or at least hanging around.